# Error while using "Protractor jasmine 2 screen shot reporter"

Tags: node.js, npm, protractor, jasmine2.0

I am trying to take the "Screen shot" of the web page when the "test case fails".

I installed "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter" using "npm".
I am using below data.

1.Node -- v6.11.4

2.NPM -- 3.10.10

3.Protractor -- 5.1.2

My "Protractor.conf.js" file code below.

```
 var HtmlScreenshotReporter  = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');

var reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
  dest: 'C:/Users/agudla/Desktop/VSCodeWorkSpace/my-app/screenshots',
  filename: 'my-report.html'
});

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  multiCapabilities: [{
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'seleniumAddress':'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'
  },
  {'browserName': 'firefox',
    'marionette': 'false',
    'seleniumAddress':'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'    
   }
  ],
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  beforeLaunch: function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
      reporter.beforeLaunch(resolve);
    });
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
  },
  // Close the report after all tests finish
  afterLaunch: function(exitCode) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
      reporter.afterLaunch(resolve.bind(this, exitCode));
    });
  }

};
```

I am getting below error message while running the test script.
 ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444

Can any one help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Check if your selenium server is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now , i run "Selenium server" and i changed the var HtmlScreenshotReporter  = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter'); as

var Jasmine2HtmlReporter  = require('C:/Users/agudla/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');

Should have to provide complete "path" for the "protractor jasmine2 html reporter".

To know the "protractor jasmine2 html reporter" path in your system , type below command in command prompt.
npm link protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter 
It will print the complete path .